# Matlab - inpolygon() and cell arrays

Tags: matlab, plot, simulation, geometry

I need to determine whether any points from a set are within a circle. I need to do the same for rectangular objects, which i have accomplished using inpolygon(). I tried to use bsxfun, as i have before for the circle, however it raises an error each time. The data is read out of an array of building information, shown below. inBuildingX and inBuildingY are the X and Y coordinates of each building in the list. For the array 'buildings' the values are, going across the row, xcentre, ycentre, vertical height(not used). length OR radius, and width. I need an inBuilding condition for buildings 2 and 6, which are circles and thus have no width. For example the first row in the array 'buildings' is a rectangle centred at (0,-300), verticle height of 30, length of 200 and width of 100. The loop works for the rectangular buildings, but not the circular ones.

[image]

```
inBuildingX = []; inBuildingY = []; inBuilding = [];
for i = 1:size(buildings,1)
    if buildings(i,5)
        inBuildingX(i,:) = [buildings(i,1)-buildings(i,4)*0.5,...
            buildings(i,1)+buildings(i,4)*0.5,...
            buildings(i,1)+buildings(i,4)*0.5,...
            buildings(i,1)-buildings(i,4)*0.5,...
            buildings(i,1)-buildings(i,4)*0.5]; 
        inBuildingY(i,:) = [buildings(i,2)-buildings(i,5)*0.5,...
            buildings(i,2)-buildings(i,5)*0.5,...
            buildings(i,2)+buildings(i,5)*0.5,...
            buildings(i,2)+buildings(i,5)*0.5,...
            buildings(i,2)-buildings(i,5)*0.5];
        inBuilding(i,:) = inpolygon(XY(1,:),XY(2,:),inBuildingX(1,:),inBuildingY(1,:));
    else     
        inBuilding(i,:) = sum(bsxfun(@minus, XY, [buildings(i,1),buildings(i,2)]).^2, 2) < (buildings(i,4)).^2;
    end
end
```

When i attempt to use the bsxfun function, it raises the error 'Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other'.

Comment: Where does the variable `XY` come from in your code?

Comment: Its initialised to contain the coordinates of all the bots
XY = zeros(botIn(1),3,'double');
for i = 1:botIn(1)
    XY(i,:) = uav{i}.position;
end

Comment: Belive i solved it, by setting @minus, XY(1:2), didnt realise that XY also contained the z component of position as well